# How to construct dynamic query over multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I'm not sure how to formulate this query. I think I need a subquery? Here's basically what I'm trying to do in a single query.

This query gives me the list of tables I need:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'abc_dev_12345' 
AND table_name like 'fact_%';
```

For the list of tables given, then I want to do a count from each table_name (each table_name has the same column info I need to query)

```
SELECT table_name,
       count (domain_key) key_count,
       domain_key,
       form_created_datetime
FROM (List of tables above)
GROUP BY domain_key,
         form_created_datetime;
```

Can I iterate through each table listed in the first query to do my count?
Do this in a single query?

So expected out would be similar to this:

```
table_name |  key_count | domain_key | form_created_datetime
--------------------------------------------------------------
fact_1        1241                 5   2015-09-22 01:47:36.136789
fact_2          32                 9   2015-09-22 01:47:36.136789
```

Example data:

```
abc_dev_12345=> SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
where table_schema='abc_dev_own_12345'
and table_name='fact_1';
 table_catalog |   table_schema    |     table_name     | table_type | self_referencing_column_name | reference_generation | user_defined_type_catalog | user_defined_type_schema | use
r_defined_type_name | is_insertable_into | is_typed | commit_action
---------------+-------------------+--------------------+------------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------+----
--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------------
 abc_dev_12345 | abc_dev_own_12345 | fact_1 | BASE TABLE |                              |                      |                           |                          |
                    | YES                | NO       |
(1 row)


abc_dev_12345=> SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'abc_dev_own_12345'
  AND table_name   = 'fact_1';
      column_name
------------------------
 email_date_key
 email_time_key
 customer_key
 form_created_datetime
 client_key
 domain_key
```

Comment: Does information_schema.tables has the column domain_key  and form_created_datetime ? Can you give some sample data from your list of tables along with other column values which you want?

Comment: I guess I can query information_schema for the column names of those same tables too?

Comment: Sorry I dont know postgresql. But if you can show some data from information_schema.tables which matches with your desired output, I can help you with the query.

Comment: added output from querying information_schema (tables, columns). Do a join on tables, columns from information_schema?

Comment: @noober, yes information_schema also contains a table called columns in which you can find information about the columns of all tables.

Comment: @utsav, if you do not know postgresql it might be good to know that informations_schema is actually the ansi catalog describing what is in the database. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/information-schema.html

Comment: @noober I do not see a way todo this as a single query as I do not belief there is a way to make the tables in the from variables. However you can write a plpgsql function or code block that iterates over the list of tables from the first querie and dynamically generates and executes queries based on that result.

Comment: @Eelke - that's what I figured. Do you have such an example or can point me to construct this?

Comment: You need dynamic SQL, using plpgsql and `EXECUTE`. There are many examples here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Like Eelke and Craig Ringer noted, you need a dynamic query in a `plpgsql` function. The basic statement you want to apply to each table is:

```
SELECT <table_name>, count(domain_key) AS key_count, domain_key, form_created_datetime
FROM <table_name> GROUP BY 3, 4
```

and you want to `UNION` the lot together.

The most efficient way to do this is to first build a query as a `text` object from the information in `information_schema.tables` and then `EXECUTE` that query. There are many ways to build that query, but I particularly like the below dirty trick with `string_agg()`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION table_domains()
RETURNS TABLE (table_name varchar, key_count bigint, domain_key integer, form_created_datetime timestamp)
AS $$
DECLARE
  qry text;
BEGIN
  -- format() builds query for individual table
  -- string_agg() UNIONs queries from all tables into a single statement
  SELECT string_agg(
    format('SELECT %1$I, count(domain_key), domain_key, form_created_datetime
            FROM %1$I GROUP BY 3, 4', table_name),
    ' UNION ') INTO qry
  FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE table_schema = 'abc_dev_12345' 
    AND table_name LIKE 'fact_%';

  -- Now EXECUTE the query
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE qry;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

No need for loops or cursors so pretty efficient.

Use like you would any other table:

```
SELECT * FROM table_domains();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm trying to create the function now, but getting this. Not sure where its coming from: `psql:crTestFunction.sql:20: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "qry"
LINE 18:   RETURN QUERY qry;`

Comment: Try `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`.

Comment: Brilliant answer, but there's a typo in the final line of the function. You have "LANGUAGE" spelled as "LANGAUGE".

Comment: @M.Andersen Muslim carpet weavers deliberately introduce a mistake in their carpets - usually inconspicuously in a corner - because only Allah can achieve perfection. This was my feeble attempt at staying a small step away from brilliance.